# Oracle SQL: Update a table column using another table referenced by 3rd table in-between

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I currently have three tables as below:

table 1

```
book_id    margin
-------------------
   b1       10
   b2       20
   b3       30
```

table 2

```
t2_id   book_id     author_id
-----------------------------
  1         b1        100
  2         b2        200
  3         b3        300
```

table 3

```
author_id    revenue
----------------------
   100          0
   200          0
   300          0
```

I am trying to update revenue on table3 with 50% of the margin from table1 for the corresponding author (on table3) of the book. The outcome should update the table 3 to:

```
author_id    revenue
----------------------
   100          10
   200          20
   300          30
```

I can update values from another table if they are directly linked together with a common key, I am struggling having to reference another table in the middle to get to the answer :(

I have tried:

```
UPDATE table3 t3 SET revenue = 
(SELECT t1.margin FROM table1 t1 WHERE
(SELECT t1.book_id FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.book_id = t2.book_id) = 
(SELECT author_id FROM table3 t3 JOIN table2 t2 ON t3.authoer_id = t2.author_id));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `update with join`

```
update 
(
SELECT table3.revenue as OLD, table1.margin as NEW
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 on table1.book_id=table2.book_id
inner join table3 on table2.author_id=table3.author_id
)t set t.old=t.new
```

Comment: Thanks, your code works well but apparently, my data has a whole lot  more issues  such as needing groupby and groupby table returning nulls etc.....arrrgh

Answer (score 1):

use merge update with a subquery

```
 MERGE INTO table3 t3 
 using 
 (select t1.margin,t2.author_id
 from tabl1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.book_id=t2.book_id
  ) a ON (t3.author_id = a.author_id)
 when matchced then
 update SET t3.revenue = a.margin
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `update` by using `with..as` method also :

```
update table3 t3
set t3.revenue = 
    (with t as (
                 select * 
                   from table1 t1
                   join table2 t2 on t2.book_id = t1.book_id
                )
                select t.margin from t where t.author_id = t3.author_id);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2abc8cf7003457d5246a13c44ae5aba3)</kbd>